# How to get parent product data from parent id for configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I want to get parent product data for configurable products.

I have parent id

How do I get it?

Comment: As a parent configurable product you can get the children simple products. Likewise as a child simple product you can get the parent. Do you want to do either of these?

Comment: then load the product data based on id use ProductRepositoryInterface  and call getById function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Got the solution

```
 use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
 use \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
```

Then in construct function use

```
public function __construct(ProductRepository $_productloader,Configurable $configurable) {
$this->configurable=$configurable;
$this->_productloader=$_productloader;
}
```

get parent product id by product id

```
 $productId='get your product id'

 $parentId=$this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
```

$parentId gives an array

then get parent product data by

$parentProductData=$this->_productloader->getById($parentId[0]);

This worked for me.

Comment: I had comment the same thing above